# Delete Duplicate Lines Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, duplicates, lines

I working on a json file, I think. But Regardless, I'm working with a lot of different hashes and fetching different values and etc. This is

```
{"notification_rule"=>
  {"id"=>"0000000",
   "contact_method"=>
    {"id"=>"000000",
     "address"=>"cod.lew@gmail.com",}
{"notification_rule"=>
  {"id"=>"000000"
   "contact_method"=>
      {"id"=>"PO0JGV7",
       "address"=>"cod.lew@gmail.com",}
```

Essential, this is the type of hash I'm currently working with. With my code:
I wanted to stop duplicates of the same thing in the text file. Because whenever I run this code it brings both the `address` of both these hashes. And I understand why, because its looping over again, but I thought this code that I added would help resolve that issue:

**Final UPDATE**

```
  if jdoc["notification_rule"]["contact_method"]["address"].to_s.include?(".com")
            numbers.print "Employee Name: "
            numbers.puts jdoc["notification_rule"]["contact_method"]["address"].gsub(/@target.com/, '').gsub(/\w+/, &:capitalize)
            file_names = ['Employee_Information.txt']
            file_names.each do |file_name|
                text = File.read(file_name)
                lines = text.split("\n")
                new_contents = lines.uniq.join("\n")
                File.open(file_name, "w") { |file| file.puts new_contents }
            end
        else 
            nil
        end
```

Comment: What's not clear here is what's in that text file. Is it email addresses? If so, why isn't `line` used inside your loop? Also testing `== true` is pointless, you can just branch on that logical value to start with.

Comment: Yes it is email addresses. And how and why would that be in the loop?

Comment: You tell me. What code you have here really doesn't make any sense, so I'm guessing it's incomplete.

Comment: Ouch...But check the update, is that what you mean?

Comment: That looks better, as at least there's something going on inside the `if`, so that at least gives an idea of the intent.

Comment: `if duplicate.exists? == true` is the same thing as `if duplicate.exists?`. Set up your text editor with a ruby linter and it will warn you when you do redundant things like that.

Comment: Ohh. Thank you! I shall remember this information

Answer (score 0):

This code looks really confused and lacking a specific purpose. Generally Ruby that's this tangled up is on the wrong track, as with Ruby there's usually a simple way of expressing something simple, and testing for duplicated addresses is one of those things that shouldn't be hard.

One of the biggest sources of confusion is the *responsibility* of a chunk of code. In that example you're not only trying to import data, loop over documents, clean up email addresses, and test for duplicates, but somehow facilitate printing out the results. That's a lot of things going on all at once, and they all have to work perfectly for that chunk of code to be fully operational. There's no way of getting it partially working, and no way of knowing if you're even on the right track.

Always try and break down complex problems into a few simple stages, then chain those stages together as necessary.

Here's how you can define a method to clean up your email addresses:

```
def address_scrub(address)
  address.gsub(/\@target.com/, '').gsub(/\w+/, &:capitalize)
end
```

Where that can be adjusted as necessary, and presumably *tested* to ensure it's working correctly, which you can now do indepenedently of the other code.

As for the rest, it looks like this:

```
require 'set'

# Read in duplicated addresses from a file, clean up with chomp, using a Set
# for fast lookups.
duplicates = Set.new(
  File.open("Employee_Information.txt", "r").readlines.map(&:chomp)
)

# Extract addresses from jdoc document array
filtered = jdocs.map do |jdoc|
  # Convert to jdoc/address pair
  [ jdoc, address_scrub(jdoc["notification_rule"]["contact_method"]["address"]) ]
end.reject do |jdoc, address|
  # Remove any that are already in the duplicates list
  duplicates.include?(address)
end.map do |jdoc, _|
  # Return only the document
  jdoc
end
```

Where that processes `jdocs`, an array of `jdoc` structures, and removes duplicates in a series of simple steps.

With the chaining approach you can see what's happening before you add on the next "link", so you can work incrementally towards a solution, adjusting as you go. Any mistakes are fairly easy to catch because you're able to, at any time, inspect the intermediate products of those stages.

Comment: Ok. Let me fully understand this. The first box that starts with `def`defines the email addresses for future purposes. I don't know what `require 'set'` does? And that code box should be placed after the code that puts those addresses inside the text file. Then it filters and creates it easy to take out the duplicates? I'm sorry. I'm completely knew to Ruby - but isn't this Ruby on Rails? Thank you for helping me by the way.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with Ruby as a whole it's worth getting a [good reference guide](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/) as a companion to guide you through your learning. `require 'set'` imports the Set library, which is [documented here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html). If you're ever curious about a component of Ruby, it's probably in the docs or on RubyGems, one of those two places.

Comment: The way you've defined the code there takes one `jdoc` and attempts to iterate over it. I've termed it `jdocs` here because presumably you have an array of *multiple* documents, each with that inner structure, as you hint at in the (incomplete) first bit of Ruby code with two separate `notification_rule` entries.

Comment: I see. Let me run through it again. Thank you for your resources.

Comment: I ran it and it gave me the same error `undefined local variable or method `jdocs' for main:Object (NameError)` Am I doing somethign wrong?

Comment: You need `jdocs` to be an array of multiple `jdoc` structures, or you need to call that chunk of code once *per* `jdoc` you find.

Comment: Shi. I forgot to say this and would probably be important but I have a `numbers = File.open("Employee_Information.txt", "w+")` and the beginning and a `numbers.close` at the end.

Comment: Aren't these hashes?

Comment: An array of hashes is a thing, and it's what you need here if you're processing more than one record. `numbers` is not relevant here, as the thing with `readlines` takes care of it. Also why is that called "numbers" if you're talking about email addresses? Is that actually something else?

Comment: Well its supposed to spit out their phone numbers but it keeps duplicating their email.

Comment: Which it does, but that duplicate thing is annoying

Comment: Maybe you're not explaining the requirements very well. You'll need to be more specific about a) what you're working with data wise, b) your expected results, and c) how the code you have here relates to it.

Comment: OK. I'll try my best. I was given a project to retrieve certain values from different apis. I've found those employees numbers and was tasked to get that as well. So what the file variable numbers is supposed to contain is - Their Name, Email, and Number. The code that I asked for help was supposed to delete the duplicates of the value  `jdoc["notification_rule"]["contact_method"]["address"]` to make it more presentable. As you can see why - because of the two different hashes that have the same values.

Comment: If you have an array of `jdoc` documents you can use the [`uniq`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) function to quickly remove duplicate entries: `jdocs.uniq { |jdoc| jdoc[...] }` where `...` is the path you have there, as before. It uses that block result to do uniqueness comparisons, as in the docs.

Comment: Ok. I will try that.

Comment: So scratch you whole plan and just `jdocs.uniq { |jdoc| jdoc["notification_rule"]["contact_method"]["address"] }` do that?

Comment: *If* `jdocs` is an array of `jdoc` structures with exactly that internal structure and you want to unique on the `address` field, then yes.